# What does 'on her detail' mean?

Tags: meaning

Wait till you hear this.
According to Carlton, she likes all the officers on her detail except one.  Officer Bloomwell.

What does 'on her detail' mean?

Please, answer me.

Comment: Have you tried consulting a dictionary?

Comment: Hi, user91178. Welcome to ELL. We normally ask people to have done a little research, tried to figure it out on their own before asking here. So that we can know that you've done that, it helps if you indicate, for example, what dictionaries you have consulted and why you are having trouble fitting what you found there to your problem. In this case, it is a relatively unusual use of *detail*, so I've answered, but it would be best if you included such information in future - and also if you edited this question to add that information.

Comment: (Note: I answered by going and finding what this came from in order to establish context - it would have been easier, and better etiquette, if you had established that context yourself.)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Merriam-Webster dictionary -

Detail - selection of a person or group for a particular task (as in military service)

Her "detail" is her group/squad.

Answer (score 1):

Having done a little digging into the source ("Blue Bloods", season 8 episode 5), this seems to be about a ***security detail***. A public figure, VIP, or someone otherwise receiving official or private security protection will have a security detail, the group of people who provide their personal security. They will act as bodyguards, scope crowds for threats, do general close protection, and often keep the media (journalists, photographers etc) off (largely because the media could conceal a threat).

Thus, the mayor (a woman) likes everyone on her security detail - that is, all the members of the detail - except one. That one is also a woman, and apparently that's what she doesn't like about her.